# Read data from Highcharts

Tags: java, highcharts, web-crawler

I am developing a crawler program based on java that extracts data from some websites. An item I'd like to have it's data in my database is a time series highcharts. What is the simplest way I can pars a highcharts and extract its data?

Answer (score 1):

In the Highcharts.charts you have an array of all charts on website. Each each has a reference to series array, where points are kept. One solution is got data from processedYData / processedXData or second from points. Example of extracting data from first chart and first serie.

Example 1:

```
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].processedYData;
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].processedXData;
```

Example 2:

```
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data 
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].points
```

Comment: I am developing crawler and need to extract highcharts data from rendered web page.

Comment: From SVG it can be complicated, our crawler use a CURL to download page or only scan a html without access to javascript ?

Comment: I can download any resources from the website. But I am looking for a simple way to parse SVG data. Please take a look at following link: "http://www.digikala.com/Product/DKP-37137/Huawei-Honor-6-H60-L04/%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%B4%D9%8A-%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%8A%D9%84-Huawei-%D8%A2%D9%86%D8%B1-6-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-H60-L04". there is a highchart at the end of page. How can I parse it?

Comment: Generally information about points you can extract from JS files (where series are defined) or when chart's data is from JSON, catch this file.

Comment: OK, where is the JS or JSON url?

Comment: Well I dont have acces to your crawler, I can point you only where these objects exists, like in my answer or comments.

Comment: This method does not work for chart 3 of this site: https://www.dep.lazio.it/covid/covid_map.php  This chart/map contains a series of 378 values like other charts, but one series per each day, so I need to find an array of around 40 elements, each one containing a 378 items series.

Comment: sorry, chart [1], not chart [3]